# Draw a hatched circle in android

Tags: android, draw, geometry

Does anyone know how i can draw programmatically in android something like this (without using opengl)?

[Pic](http://i56.tinypic.com/2yn1ldj.png)

Comment: Try this, It may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566091/android-draw-circle-pixel-by-pixel?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can use [shape drawables](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) (circles and lines) to define elements and then combine them in one drawable with [Layer List](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList). All this can be defined in XML.

Comment: There is no way to use xml, because i compute the radius of the circle inside java. What i have done so far is using a BitmapShader to repeat my lines. The problem is now, that the inner circle as this texture, too. So how can i make the inner circle transparent, so that my background image (google maps view) is visible again.