# Android Draw Circle Pixel by Pixel

Tags: android, view, draw, pixel, geometry

I am trying to draw a circle on my bitmap, pixel by pixel, using this code:

```
for(int j = ((int)x - 20); j < ((int)x + 20); j++){
    for(int k = ((int)y - 20); k < ((int)y + 20); k++){

        int colorX = bitmap.getPixel((int)j, (int)k);

        if(Color.red(colorX) == 0 && Color.green(colorX) == 0 && Color.blue(colorX) == 0){

            if(Math.sqrt(((j - (( int ) x )) ^ 2 ) + ((k - (( int ) y )) ^ 2) ) <= 20)
                bitmap.setPixel(j, k, Color.YELLOW);
        }
    }

}
```

But there is a problem, this is not drawing a circle.. it looks like a triangle..

Can someone help me?

Thanks alot in advance ;)

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do it this way instead of using `Canvas`?

Comment: Yes there are, I need to check every pixel at j, k to see the color. I only draw a pixel yellow if the pixel below is black

Comment: @Deev I editted the question, to show you that I need to do this way.. because I need to check the color of pixel

Comment: see what ^ operator means in java

Comment: and btw what you are doing is probably a bad. idea, you should most likely use porter duff xfer modes

Comment: Yes the problem was the ^ operator, I used now Math.pow(value, 2) and its working :D   Thanks alot !   What do you mean by porter duff xfer modes ? what is that ?

Comment: Put your answer of ^ operator , and I will accept it ;)

Comment: read this http://ssp.impulsetrain.com/porterduff.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your mistake is a wrong use of ^ , its not a power operator

regarding xfer modes i mentioned in the comment, see this custom view:

```
class V extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    Xfermode mode = new AvoidXfermode(Color.BLACK, 0, AvoidXfermode.Mode.TARGET);

    public V(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int w = getWidth();
        float h = getHeight() / 3f;
        paint.setXfermode(null);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, w, h, paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawRect(0, h, w, 2*h, paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 2*h, w, 3*h, paint);

        // draw the circle: it draws only in the middle black strip
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setXfermode(mode);
        canvas.drawCircle(w/2, 1.5f * h, h, paint);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey psking I tested this code today, and notice that there is no difference between using paint.setXfermode(mode) or without that line... It says by the way that AvoidXfermode is deprecated.. can you test this, and tell me if it worked for u? thanks alot

Comment: it worked using Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); for the canvas :)

Comment: hmm, my code definitly worked (i tested it on the emu though),  it could not work if canvas didnot have alpha buffer, you could try to call canvas.saveLayer and canvas.restore in onDraw

Comment: For me it worked using a specific drawing on a bitmap with config ARGB_8888 :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use sin/cos formula to draw circle, Following code is written in C++ but It can easily convert to Java/Android.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <graphics.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <bios.h>
#include <math.h>

void DrawCircle(int x, int y, int r, int color)
{
      static const double PI = 3.1415926535;
      double i, angle, x1, y1;

      for(i = 0; i < 360; i += 0.1)
      {
            angle = i;
            x1 = r * cos(angle * PI / 180);
            y1 = r * sin(angle * PI / 180);
            putpixel(x + x1, y + y1, color);
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I used Math.pow instead of ^ operator and got solved